# ¿Que hace el selector de jQuery $({})?

Tags: jquery

Estoy haciendo una animación y he encontrado el siguiente `pen`:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/niklas-r/pen/HsjEv)

**Código del `pen`:**

```
$({percentage: 0}).stop(true).animate({percentage: value}, {
    duration : 2000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    step: function () {
        // percentage with 1 decimal;
        var percentageVal = Math.round(this.percentage * 10) / 10;

        $el.text(percentageVal + '%');
    }
})
```

**Selector:**

**`$({percentage: 0})`**`.stop(true)`**`.animate({percentage: value}, {...});`**

- ¿Que cambia?
- ¿Para que sirve?
- En caso de especificar propiedades de `jQuery` , ¿Que hace la de `percentage`?

---

Supongo que `jquery` tendra un `JSON` de propiedades y se cambiaran de está manera, pero no lo había visto antes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$({percentage: 0})` es el contexto en el cual la animacion va a trabajar y cuando le indicas cual es la propiedad en el metodo `animate()`, este buscara la propiedad indicada sobre el contexto y le aplica la animacion.

Si te fijas, notaras como en el cuerpo de `step()` se utiliza `this` para acceder a la propiedad `porcentage` definida en el objeto pasado por el constructor de jquery, que es el contexto:

```
 step: function () {
             // accediendo al contexto provisto en el constructor de jquery
                                        ↓
        var percentageVal = Math.round(this.percentage * 10) / 10;

        $el.text(percentageVal + '%');
    }
```

**TL;DR**
`{percentage: 0}` representa el contexto enviado al constructor de jquery. `.animate({percentage: value},{})` representa la propiedad a animar basado en el contexto.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Einer! No encontraba nada de info sobre esto...